# How to avoid calling a method in unit tests?

Tags: c++, multithreading, testing

I'm writing tests for a class A. The behavior this class is supposed to implement is starting a connection to a backend system. It offers the public function `StartConnection()` via its interface.

```cpp
void A::StartConnection(const std::string uri) {
  // various method calls...
  StartIocThread();
  // more method calls and stuff to do...
}
```

`StartConnection` includes calls to various private methods, such as a method to regex the URI or set up handler. One of these methods is called `StartIocThread` which launches a new thread which will later invoke the handlers.

```cpp
void A::StartIocThread() {
  std::thread([&] { ioc_.run(); }).detach();
}
```

Now obviously I don't want a new thread to be detached every time I run the `StartConnection` unit test. However, this method gets called inside the `StartConnection()` method. What is the best way to prevent a new thread being created every time?

The only way I can think of right now is putting that method inside a different class which I can then mock in the unit test. But that seems like a lot of overhead (including dependency injection) just to prevent this method from being called.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not? why do you not want to test the actual behaviour? the thread does terminate gracefully right? I would mock the backend server and check the actual connection.

Comment: I don't need a full mock of the backend server at the moment. I'm perfectly fine with just assuring that the API methods (which are wrapped by a separate class) are called at the right moment with the right parameters.

Comment: To answer your second point: I don't know if it's a good idea to always start a detached thread every time that unit test is run. If you can convince be that it doesn't matter, then fine :D

Comment: It does not need to be a full mock but a light weight one really. In that case you are better of creating an abstracion class and wrap your lower level calls in them like have your own CreateThread(), CreateMtx etc and override them as you will.

Comment: why does `A` start and detach the thread? If the line in the method would be just `ioc_.create_thread_and_run()` you could mock `ioc_` to do nothing in that method for the test

Comment: @user463035818 ioc is actually an object of a class of the boost library called io_context. Yes, mocking that class would be another possibility. I'd have to look into the class it inherits from to see if mocking that is possible.

Comment: tbh I dont really understand the question. As I understand it the answer definitely is dependency injection, however you already mention it and want to avoid it, but then what else do you want?

Comment: I don't want to avoid it. I just wanted to ask if there's another way that I should consider instead of dependency injection. Because creating a class that simply starts a new thread on a given ioc object and having to inject that class seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: Another possibility is that You have 2 cpp files with the implementation of `void A::StartIocThread()`. 1) A file with the real implementation which is linked with the release code, 2) a file with an empty/test/mock implementation which is linked with the test project. But this can be a headache.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :) I decided to go with a standard dependency injection for now.